# API Gateway - Receiving 'not authorized to perform' error when calling API Gateway endpoint

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify from my Node.js server.

I successfully logged in, however when calling a get function I get the following error.

I have configured my resource with Auth: None and Resource policy is blank so I can get it working. But it seems that is still failing because of permissions somewhere else.

User: ..../Auth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: {action}

I expect that setting auth to None and resource policy leave it blank, to have the endpoint succeed.

Comment: What is your cognito auth role policy?

Comment: Thanks for your question. Actually, I didn't realise to check Identity Pool role policy. The problem was that APIGateway wasn't included on my Auth role policy.

Comment: So is it fixed now?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed! Thank you so much.